# Preferred form of nominalization

Tags: nominalization

When writing project plans or the like, there are often 2 ways to nominalize verbs in order to describe activities, for instance:

**Using a suffix:**

> Testen
>
> 1. ***Entwicklung*** von Testspezifikationen
> 2. ***Generierung*** von Testdaten
> 3. ***Durchführung*** der Tests
> 4. ***Auswertung*** der Ergebnisse

vs.

**Using the infinitive:**

> Testen
>
> 1. ***Entwickeln*** von Testspezifikationen
> 2. ***Generieren*** von Testdaten
> 3. ***Durchführen*** der Tests
> 4. ***Auswerten*** der Ergebnisse

I know, both are correct, but which one should be the preferred form? I assume, the text should be consistent, so should I always use the same form? However, sometimes there are not both forms possible (or uncommon), for instance:

> ***Lesen / Studieren*** des Konzepts <--> ***Lesung(!?) / Studierung(!?) / Studium*** des Konzepts
>
> ---
>
> ***Aufnehmen*** von Berichten <--> ***Aufnehmung(!?) / Aufnahme*** von Berichten

Sometimes there are even 3 or more ways:

> ***Konzipieren*** / ***Konzipierung*** / ***Konzeption*** des [...]

Any recommendations here?

Comment: In many cases I'd just not use nouns but verbs and avoid an overly complicated structure. Frequently these nouns go along with passive voice, making the text yet another tad harder to read. In a project plan I'd rather write "Alice entwickelt die Testspezifikation", "Berta stellt Testdaten zusammen", "Conrad führt die Tests durch", etc.

Answer (score 3):

I would also read from the infinitive form like "Auswerten" more weight on the action, while "Auswertung" is geared more towards the results of the evaluation.

Comment: Correct! In some cases, a slightly different meaning is conveyed.

Answer (score 2):

Recommendation:

1. Would one way be confusing? (e.g. `Konzeption` is used in the meaning of `Konzept` as well as `das Konzipieren`.) Then use the other.
2. Have you used the term before in the same paper? Then use the same form used before.
3. Are you inside a structure, where the question arises multiple times at the same point? (e.g. your enumeration above) Then use the same form everywhere inside the structure.
4. Is there a widely used derivative (what you describe as "suffix")? (e.g. Entwicklung but not necessarily Generierung) Then use that.
5. Use the Nominalization (what you describe as infinitive).

Answer (score 2):

Whatever we "feel" as being the better choice can be seen if we look closely at the examples give.

- In case we speak of the nominalized verb *das Testen* we may also want to choose a nominalized verb in the following.
- If however we have a proper noun to where the following section relates we may prefer to use a suffixation to build a proper noun from a verb (in case there is no other noun available).

We can see this if we silghtly change the context of the given example (note that difference in meaning basically resulted in changing two letters only):

#### Suffixation:

> Unter einem **Test** verstehen wir die
>
> 1. ***Entwicklung*** von Testspezifikationen
> 2. ***Generierung*** von Testdaten
> 3. ***Durchführung*** der Tests
> 4. ***Auswertung*** der Ergebnisse

#### Nominalized verb:

> Mit **Testen** meinen wir das
>
> 1. ***Entwickeln*** von Testspezifikationen
> 2. ***Generieren*** von Testdaten
> 3. ***Durchführen*** der Tests
> 4. ***Auswerten*** der Ergebnisse

At the end it is more an issue of style than of grammar even though there is a slight shift in meaning [as was nicely explained in the answer altready given](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/7890/23).

Answer (score 1):

Consider also that nominalized forms do have differences in meaning:

> Bei der Nominalisierung werden verbale Ausdrücke in nominale Ausdrücke umgeformt, indem 
>   man Verben, Adjektivverben oder Funktionsverbgefüge durch Nomen ersetzt:
>
> - Nominalisierung von Verben:
>
>   1. nominalisierter Infinitiv:
>
>      - treffen - das Treffen
>          parken  - das Parken
>   2. Nomen auf „ung“:
>
>      - gründen - die Gründung
>          fordern - die Forderung
>   3. lexikalisiertes Nomen:
>
>      - ankommen - die Ankunft
>          beabsichtigen - die Absicht
>
> Nominalisierte Infinitive (1) bezeichnen meist nur das Geschehen selbst, evtl. 
>     existierende parallele Formen (2,3) weisen demgegenüber oft Bedeutungs- 
>     unterschiede auf
>
> das Danken (Geschehen) -  der Dank (abgeschlossene Handlung)
>     das Mischen (Geschehen) - die Mischung  (Ergebnis)
>     das Bescheinigen (Geschehen) - die Bescheinigung (Mittel)
>   <sub>http://www.wirtschaftsdeutsch.de/lehrmaterialien/grammatik-nominalisierung-A.pdf</sub>

Answer (score 0):

There are actually three ways to do this (or four if you count the Latin import). The third way is the obscure suffix "icht", which was occurs so far as I know only in the word "kehricht", or "sweepings". I learned this fact from an earlier discussion on this same site, involving some of the same parties as in the present discussion.

Oddly enough, last week I wrote an article about the three different ways of making a verb into a noun, in which I compare the English, German, and Yiddish systems. I submitted this article to the local Jewish weekly and I expect it to appear in print tomorrow. I have put up a PDF of my article [here](http://www.onforeignsoil.com/pdf/Yechts.pdf). I hope you like it.